# Finding phrases without exact match using %in%

Tags: r

I’m using the following code below to look for certain states inside a column in a dataframe called Area. The Area column has city and state typically, and other phrase as shown here. So it wouldn't find `Ohio` in `Cleveland, Ohio` for instance.

Any idea how to change the code to find partial matches by the state? Can I add a `%like%` in the code somewhere?

DataFrame called Data:

```
**Area**   
Cleveland, Ohio
Manhattan, New York
Lower Nevada
```

Code:

```
StateFunding <- c("California","North 
Carolina","Texas","Florida","Maryland","Pennsylvania","New York")
Data$Classification = "0"

for (i in 1:length(Data$Area))
{
  if(Data$Area[i] %in% StateFunding) {
   Data$Classification[i] = "InList"
  } else {
   Data$Classification[i] = "NotinList"
  }
}
```

Comment: Look into "fuzzy matching", also, if working with exact matching then you could replace the forloop with `Data$Classification <- ifelse(Data$Area %in% StateFunding, "InList", "NotinList")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
i <- rowSums(sapply(StateFunding, function(p) agrepl(p, mydf$Area))) > 0

mydf$Classification <- c('NotInList','InList')[1 + i]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > mydf
>                  Area Classification
> 1     Cleveland, Ohio      NotInList
> 2 Manhattan, New York         InList
> 3        Lower Nevada      NotInList
> ```

You can also do this with `ifelse`:

```
ifelse(rowSums(sapply(StateFunding, function(p) agrepl(p, mydf$Area))) > 0, 'InList', 'NotInList')
```

---

Used data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Area = c("Cleveland, Ohio", "Manhattan, New York", "Lower Nevada")), 
                  .Names = "Area", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `grepl` to check if one string is a substring of another string. For example:

```
for (i in 1:length(Data$Area))
{
  if(sum(sapply(StateFunding,grepl,x=Data$Area[i]))>0){
    Data$Classification[i] = "InList"
  } else {
    Data$Classification[i] = "NotinList"
  }
}
```

Comment: @zx8754, I just did. Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: This solution would work for `Ohio in Cleveland` vs `Ohio`, but would also match `BOhio in Cleveland` vs `Ohio`, which might not be what OP wants.